# Can't add workers to Docker Swarm

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, docker-swarm

So I am running VMs on VirtualBox to try to get Docker to work in distributed mode.  As per this tutorial (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#configure-a-docker-machine-shell-to-the-swarm-manager) , I set VM called "myvm1" to the be swarm manager with `ssh myvm1 "docker swarm init --advertise-addr 10.0.2.15"`,
however, when I try to add workers to that swarm, I get an error:

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = 
all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: 
connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 
10.0.2.15:2377: connect: connection refused"
exit status 1
```

where 10.0.2.15 is the IP of the manager VM I got from running `VBoxManage guestproperty get myvm1 "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"`

Anyone know what could be the cause?  Is my IP wrong?  Do I need to open ports?

FYI: To add attempt adding a worker, I tired:

`docker-machine ssh myvm2 "docker swarm join --token [token returned by swarm init on myvm1] 10.0.2.15:2377"`

Not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Nevermind: It works after using the eth1 address instead of the eth0 address

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you are running Virtual Box. This mean that some of your interfaces are shared with other VMs and the host.

If you run ifconfig on your VMs and host, Choose the interface which exhibit different IPs for every machine VM.

I had this problem, too and figured out that the eth0 IPs were the same on every machine. Of course, this cannot work.

eth1 also had different IPs for every machine.

Hope this helps.